# How can I have use and/or in case inside func.json_build_object() in sqlalchemy ORM?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, python-datetime

I want to use and/or in a case statement in Sqlalchemy ORM inside func.json_build_object().

**I tried **

```
case(
 [((Employee.join_date > inner_query.offset(1).limit(1).subquery().c.last_synced_date)
   and 
   (Employee.join_date < datetime.datetime(2022,11,14)
 ), True],
 _else = False,
)
```

**I got this error:**

```
File "/var/task/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 869, in operate
    return op(self.comparator, *other, **kwargs)
  File "/var/task/sqlalchemy/sql/operators.py", line 440, in __getitem__
    return self.operate(getitem, index)
  File "/var/task/sqlalchemy/sql/type_api.py", line 77, in operate
    return o[0](self.expr, op, *(other + o[1:]), **kwargs)
  File "/var/task/sqlalchemy/sql/default_comparator.py", line 181, in _getitem_impl
    _unsupported_impl(expr, op, other, **kw)
  File "/var/task/sqlalchemy/sql/default_comparator.py", line 185, in _unsupported_impl
    raise NotImplementedError(
NotImplementedError: Operator 'getitem' is not supported on this expression
```

Comment: please provide all query